# Events List Pagination

Tags: sxa

I am trying to add pagination for events list but it displays this message "There is no list on the page with the same signature" although the paging component and the events list are using the same list signature value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a problem with Pagination rendering in 1.4 and yes it was not working with Event List. It's already working fine in 1.5 (release within few days).

Comment: SXA 1.5 is live now! https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator/15/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator_15_Initial_Release.aspx